# Microsoft Service Configuration Editor - Could Not Load File Or Assembly

Tags: wcf, configurationmanager

I'm getting stumped by a very basic error.  I'm trying to add endpoints to a service through the `WCF Service Configuration Editor`, and it can't find the default output.  Here's every step I can take to reproduce the error.

**Add New WCF Service Application**

[image: New Project]

**Build Solution**

[image: Build]

**Edit WCF Configuration**

[image: Web.Config]

**Create New Service**

[image: New Service]

**Browse to Project Directory for Service Type**

[image: ServiceDll]

**Error Message**

[image]

This should work, but instead I get the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file://...\emptyservice\bin\EmptyService.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies.
>   Operation is not supported.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

*What am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open the 'EmptyService.dll' library in your 'bin\Debug' folder.

I had the '... `Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)`' message when trying to open the library in the 'publish' folder.  I published my service from within Visual Studio using the 'Publish Web Site' option.